# Hartl Rails tutorial chapter 8: How does remember_token work?

Tags: attributes, token, railstutorial.org

In the Michael Hartl tutorial, chapter 8, we set up the sign in page and create a new column in the database to hold a base 64 string.  In the tutorial it's called a remember_token.  In the user.rb:

```
  private

    def create_remember_token
        self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end
```

self has a property called remember_token? Is this already built in or did it get created elsewhere? Maybe I'm just not understanding this very well.

He writes:

> Because of the way Active Record synthesizes attributes based on
>   database columns, without self the assignment would create a local
>   variable called remember_token, which isn’t what we want at all. Using
>   self ensures that assignment sets the user’s remember_token so that it
>   will be written to the database along with the other attributes when
>   the user is saved.

I'm confused, how did the user get a remember token?  How does it know to write this to the database in that particular column?

In the user.rb you have the following code:

```
attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
```

There's nothing about remember_token there.  How does it know to include this at User.save?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, `self` is a User object, and it has a `remember_token` attribute because of the database column created by the migration in [Section 8.2.1](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#sec-remember_me) of the [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book). (Prepending `self` is necessary to assign to the attribute; without `self`, Ruby would just create a *local* variable called `remember_token`.)

Comment: I see. So attributes created by migrations are the same as adding to the attr_accessible? Thanks!

Comment: When I type self at the console I get "main".  I guess I should read that ruby book after this.

Comment: *All* attributes created by migrations are automatically available via Active Record, but they can't be changed via mass assignment unless part of the `attr_accessible` list.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2018, `@remember_token` has an accessor method.

https://www.railstutorial.org/book/advanced_login#code-user_model_remember

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :remember_token

  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }

  ...

# Remembers a user in the database for use in persistent sessions.
  def remember
    self.remember_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
  end

  ...
```

There is no `remember_token` column in the database. It is a 'virtual' attribute. The remember token is stored as a hash as `remember_digest` instead.